# How do I scrape a table in webpage using python?

Tags: python, scrape

I use Python to scrape [this webpage](http://us.soccerway.com/national/england/premier-league/20132014/regular-season/r21322/). But I can't take the items when you click on the previous button. I thought of using Selenium to achieve that, but I had no success making it headless.

With the code below I scrape the match links:

```
import urllib2
import re

site_url = 'http://us.soccerway.com'
national_league_div_sub_matches_url = 'http://us.soccerway.com/national/england/premier-league/20132014/regular-season/r21322/'
national_league_div_sub_matches_url_source = urllib2.urlopen(national_league_div_sub_matches_url).read()
match_links = re.findall('(/matches/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/.*?ICID.*?)">', national_league_div_sub_matches_url_source)
match_links = map(lambda x: ''.join([site_url, x]), match_links)
for x in match_links:
    print x
```

Comment: Show us what you've got so far.

Comment: use phantomjs with selenium

Comment: I tried phantomjs a few months ago and couldn't make it work. I am on windows if that matters.

Comment: just parse the json requests initiated by the button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click `previous` in browser javascript calls this long `url` to get JSON data from server - so do the same.

```
import requests, json

url = 'http://us.soccerway.com/a/block_competition_matches_summary?block_id=page_competition_1_block_competition_matches_summary_6&callback_params=%7B%22page%22%3A0%2C%22bookmaker_urls%22%3A%7B%2213%22%3A%5B%7B%22link%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bet365.com%2Fhome%2F%3Faffiliate%3D365_308124%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22Bet%20365%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%22block_service_id%22%3A%22competition_summary_block_competitionmatchessummary%22%2C%22round_id%22%3A21322%2C%22outgroup%22%3Afalse%2C%22view%22%3A2%7D&action=changePage&params=%7B%22page%22%3A-1%7D'

r = requests.get(url)

#print r.text

data = json.loads(r.text)

print data
```

Now you have `dict` in `data` so you have to find what you need.

Probably every click on `previous` in broswer change `url` so you will have to do the same if you want to get older data.